# select different column if null or empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select `state` or the `workstate` column. Preference is to first use the `state` value. If its null or empty then i want to use the `workstate` value.

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT        
COUNT(id) AS participants, 

COALESCE(NULLIF(state,''), workState, (select state from dbo.training where id =(SELECT top(1) trainingId
    FROM dbo.Xref_Participant_Training
    WHERE (participantId = dbo.Participant.id) )) ) as state

FROM dbo.Participant
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.Xref_Participant_Training
        WHERE (participantId = dbo.Participant.id) AND (dbo.Participant.country = 'United States'))
GROUP by COALESCE(NULLIF(state,''), workState, (select state from dbo.training where id =(SELECT top(1) trainingId
        FROM dbo.Xref_Participant_Training
        WHERE (participantId = dbo.Participant.id) )) )
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: include workState in the groupings.

Comment: Specify the same `COALESCE` expression in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You may want to change the final part of a coalesce to an outer apply instead of a subquery so that the result can be included in the group by.

Comment: Take a look at CTEs for Sql Server.  You can treat each of your sub-queries as tables, join across the pieces and produce a cleaner statement at the end.

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS THE ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

The issue is that you need to put the entire expression in the `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS participants, 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(p.state,''), p.workState) as state
FROM dbo.Participant p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Xref_Participant_Training pt
              WHERE pt.participantId = p.id
             ) AND
      p.country = 'United States'
GROUP BY COALESCE(NULLIF(p.state, ''), p.workState);
```

The problem with your query is that `GROUP BY state` really means `GROUP BY p.state`.  However, you want to aggregate by the column defined in the `SELECT`.

In addition:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You don't need a column name for an `EXISTS` subquery.

Comment: ok so what would happen if i had 3 options. See my updated query

Comment: @codeNinja . . . Changing the question after it has been answered is rude.  It invalidates answers and that can draw downvotes.  If you have another question, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

change the GROUP BY to include the entire expression

```
SELECT        
       COUNT(id) AS participants, 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(state,''), workState) as state
FROM   dbo.Participant
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT participantId
        FROM dbo.Xref_Participant_Training
        WHERE (participantId = dbo.Participant.id) AND (dbo.Participant.country = 'United States'))
GROUP BY COALESCE(NULLIF(state,''), workState)
```

for your updated query, when the query gets complex, it is easier to use derived table or cte

example syntax for derived table

```
select col1, col2, count(*)
from
(
    select col1, col2 = coalesce(col2, col3), col4, col5
    from   sometable
) d
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: yup that works. I want to extend it a bit further to the final state. See my updated query.